# how to reproduce successful curl call in ajax

Tags: ajax, json, charles-proxy

In Charles proxy I've captured a successful request made when using curl - which returns some json. I've tried all day to make this into an ajax call but have failed - wonder if someone could take a fresh look at it? I'm sending a token via the header to a service that provides this json

```
{
"category": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aaa",
    "description": "anything..."
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ccc",
    "description": "desc 1111..."
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "ddd",
    "description": "desc..."
}]
}
```

charles dump of the good request made with curl

```
    GET /api/v1/category HTTP/1.1
    User-Agent  curl/7.30.0
    Host    myurl.com
    Accept  */*
    Authorization   Token token=6ff1fed470ec2ddaf8b3af9584619902
```

the raw info

```
    URL http://myurl.com/api/v1/category
    Status  Complete
    Response Code   200 OK 
    Protocol    HTTP/1.1
    Method  GET
    Kept Alive  No
    Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
    Client Address  /127.0.0.1
    Remote Address  myurl.com/23.23.121.64
```

my attempt

```
$.ajax({
beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader ('Authorization', 'Token 6ff1fed470ec2ddaf8b3af9584619902') },
type: "GET",
url: "http://myurl.com/api/v1/category",
dataType: "json"
}).done(function( msg ) {
console.log( msg );

}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
console.log( errorThrown );
});
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You haven’t posted the diagnostics for your attempt, so I’m just going to guess from your code.

1. You send

   `Authorization: Token 6ff1fed470ec2ddaf8b3af9584619902`

   from XHR, but

   `Authorization: Token token=6ff1fed470ec2ddaf8b3af9584619902`

   from curl—note the `token=`.
2. You have to make sure that `http://myurl.com/api/v1/category` either supports [cross-origin resource sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) or is located at the same origin (domain) as the page that executes that JavaScript code.

If these do not help, post whatever error messages you get.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My attempt is to set a separate api to the client, so will look at what's needed for CORS support. So far I am returning the result in JSONP. What's interesting is in Charles Proxy, if I edit a failed request and paste in a new line "Authorization: Token token=1234 etc .. then it works. Nothing I can do will make that stick in setRequestHeader though.

Comment: @MikeW If you want JSONP, your `$.ajax` call is incorrect, check the docs. Otherwise please post diagnostics for your failing case.